# RestController Junit when issue in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have an issue to write a RestControler Junit in Spring Boot. I have a problem in listBook in when option.

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the method of restController shown below.

```
@GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<List<BookResponse>> listBook(@RequestParam(name = "size") int size, @RequestParam(name = "page") int page) {
        final Long userID = userService.findInContextUser().getId();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bookListService.listBooks(size, page, userID));
    }
```

Here is the test method shown below

```
@Test
    void itShouldGetBooks_WhenSearch() throws Exception {

        // given - precondition or setup
        BookResponse response1 = BookResponse.builder()
                .title("Book 1")
                .authorName("authorName")
                .build();

        BookResponse response2 = BookResponse.builder()
                .title("Book 1")
                .authorName("authorName2")
                .build();

        List<BookResponse> response = List.of(response1, response2);

        UserDto userDto = UserDto.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .username("username")
                .build();

        // when -  action or the behaviour that we are going test
        when(userService.findInContextUser()).thenReturn(userDto);
        when(bookListService.listBooks(anyInt(), anyInt(), eq(userDto.getId()))).thenReturn(response);

        // then - verify the output
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/book/search?size=" + anyInt() + "&page=" + anyInt()) // HERE IS THE ERROR LINE
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2))) // ERROR IS HERE
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Here is the error message shown below.

```
    java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$"
Expected: a collection with size <2>
     but: was LinkedHashMap <{error=Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
```

Comment: "size parameter is missing" returned from your endpoint should be pretty clear, shouldn't it?

Comment: @knittl I edited my post. I added size and page parameter but I got the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution shown below.

Change

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/book/search?size=" + anyInt() + "&page=" + anyInt())
```

to

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/book/search?size=" + 1 + "&page=" + 1)
```

Comment: If you want to perform a request, you need to pass values. `anyInt()` passes a dummy value (`0`). Also note that you could simply call `mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/book/search?size=1&page=1")` without concatenating strings

Answer (score 0):

Your method is called `listBook` but you are mocking `listBooks` (note the s). `listBook` is defined with 2 parameters (int, int), but your mock is set up with 3 matchers (int, int, id). Furthermore, you cannot mix matchers with literal values. Either all arguments are matchers or none are (i.e. all are real values).

```
//                             vvvvvv----vvvvvv-- any matchers
when(bookListService.listBooks(anyInt(), anyInt(), eq(userDto.getId())))
//                                                 ^^-- equality matcher
        .thenReturn(response);
```

Comment: @S.N now it's a different question (and a different error). The original problem was solved. The new question should be: "how to assert an object with mockmvc and jsonpath to contain a specific number of properties". Or perhaps "how to pass parameters via mockmvc?"